# Delete rows in a large table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large table from which I want to delete entire rows corresponding to specific value of column A. I use for loop but I am looking for a more efficient way.

```
Sub deleteRow()
    For i = 1 To 900000
        If Cells(i, 1) > 7 Then
            Rows(i).Select
            Selection.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You can apply a filter and then using `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` you can delete all at once. That will be much faster and efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple Macro will work for you:

## No Need for Loop

For a Table use this:

```
Sub deleteRow()

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1") ' Change table name

        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">7"
        .DataBodyRange.Delete

    End With

End Sub
```

It will also show a warning, select Yes when it appears

---

For Simple Range Object Use this:

```
Sub deleteRow()

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange

        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">7"
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete xlShiftUp

    End With

End Sub
```

Useful Link with Various of Table Operation Commands. [Here](http://realanalysiszone.com/?p=19)

Comment: What's up @mikku! Let's race! I think you'll win... but I'll set it up!

Comment: Hahaha @PGCodeRider .... I am not riding Codes like you do Man! :) Enjoy the ride

Comment: Oh you crushed me 12 seconds vs 0 seconds... although mine didn't filter the whole sheet. Here's the racing code: https://pastebin.com/e8kRVXx5

I surrender! Have a good night1

Comment: @Mikku Thanks. My data is already in an excel table. how can I modify this code to use for such data? and then clear the filter to show the remaining rows?

Comment: @Hamtash .. Added answer for a Table. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should delete them all at once at the end rather than on each instance.

Try this.

```
Sub deleteRow()
Dim killRNG As Range
Set killRNG = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).EntireRow

For i = 1 To 900000


If Cells(i, 1) > 7 Then

Set killRNG = Union(Cells(i, 1).EntireRow, killRNG)

End If
Next i

killRNG.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Tips:

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteRow()

    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

    'Create a with statement refer to the sheet where data are store
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find LastRow of column A. There is no need to loop up to 900000
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'When you loop aiming to delete you loop from bottom to top
        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1

            'In both ".Cells(i, 1) > 7" & ".Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete" we use "." before
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value > 7 Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```